# How Can I Hide jsp folder path and file name in application

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, servlets, url-rewriting

I have a web application -
But when I navigate from menus and other links, the address bar displays folder and file name.
What I would like to have is whatever navigation the user do, the address bare should only display

```
http://domain:port/daswebapp
```

rather than

```
http://domain:port/daswebapp/admin/index.jsp
```

Can anybody help on this. I don't use any other framework.Its a pure MVC pattern.
Thanks n Regards
Noufal

Comment: I guess you could use framesets, or use Ajax/DHTML to load all pages. But why? How important is this for you (and your users)?

Comment: Hi Jigar ,Thanx for response.  The reason is in the address bar servlet name will be shown like http://domain:port/daswebapp/servletname without extension. if user enters in the address bar it will show exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use url rewrite filter such as [urlrewritefilter](http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/), for JSF based app go for [Pretty faces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/)

> The main things it is used for are:

- **URL Tidyness** / URL Abstraction - keep URLs tidy irrespective of the underlying technology or framework (JSP, Servlet, Struts etc).
- **Browser Detection** - Allows you to rewrite URLs based on request HTTP headers (such as user-agent or charset).
- **Date based rewriting** - Allows you to forward or redirect to other URL's based on the

  date/time (good for planned outages).
- **Moved content** - enable a graceful move of content or even a change in CMS.
- **Tiny/Friendly** URL's (i.e. blah.com/latest can be redirected to blah.com/download/ver1.2.46.2/setup.exe)
- A Servlet mapping engine (see Method Invocation)

Comment: But then it would still show some URL unique to the page (just a different one). I don't think that can be helped, though.

Comment: @Thilo _What I would like to have is whatever navigation the user do, the address bare should only display "http://domain:port/daswebapp" rather than "http://domain:port/daswebapp/admin/index.jsp"_ based on this it clearly seems that OP is looking for rewrite filter

Comment: If you say so. My understanding of a rewrite filter is that navigating to different pages still ends up as different URL, so the address bar would display different things depending on what navigation the user does.

Answer (score 0):

you can use RequestDispatcher,

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getRequestDispatcher("daswebapp/admin/index.jsp");
   dispatcher.forward( request, response );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this try out and let me know

```
RequestDispatcher reqDisp = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
            reqDisp.forward(request, response);
```